# Import alfresco project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, alfresco

I'm new in Alfresco I have download and installed "alfresco-community-4.2.f-installer-win-x64.exe" and I'm looking if I can import it as an eclipse project

Comment: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK_4.0#Downloading_and_Installing_the_SDK

Answer (score 0):

The Alfresco Installer provides everything you need to run Alfresco. Install it, start it, away you go

However, if you want to either write your own Java code to run on Alfresco, or to extend/change Alfresco, it isn't what you need.

To build your own code on top of Alfresco, you'll most likely want the [Alfresco SDK](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK). That contains everything you need to:

- Develop Alfresco Repository plug-ins such as:

  - Custom Actions / Conditions
  - Custom Aspects
  - Custom Transformers
- Develop Applications against a standalone Alfresco server via Alfresco's Web Service API. In this case, the SDK works as a wrapper for the Alfresco API.
- Embed Alfresco into existing Applications via Alfresco's Java Foundation API or standards-compliant JCR API

Alternately, if you want to make changes to Alfresco itself, then you'll need to grab the source code for it. The [Source Code Wiki Page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Source_Code) has the details of how to do that, and the [4.2f code is here](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2f/root/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Maven you can try with [Maven Alfresco SDK](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/alfresco-docs/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/index.html)